# Pytube: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Tags: python, youtube, attributeerror, pytube

I created this code for YouTube downloads, but it gives me this error:

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

while True:
    url = input("Enter the video link: ")

    print("Uploading the video...")
    print("Authot: " + url.author)
   
    pytube.YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
    print("Video scaricato")

    loop = input("\nDo you want to continue using the program ?: ")
    if loop == "Yes" or loop == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

Answer (score 0):

The variable `url` will hold whatever value the user enters. This will therefore be a value of type `str`. Therefore it is not possible to do `url.author`.

Answer (score 0):

url is a string, you have to get the author from the pytube object

```
import pytube
from pytube import YouTube

while True:
    url = input("Enter the video link: ")

    print("Uploading the video...")
    print("Authot: " + pytube.YouTube(url).author)

    pytube.YouTube(url).streams.get_highest_resolution().download()

    print("Video scaricato")

    loop = input("\nDo you want to continue using the program ?: ")
    if loop == "Yes" or loop == "yes":
        continue
    else:
        break
```